# Is there a closed form for the $n$th integral of a polynomial?

Tags: calculus, integration

Say I have some polynomial $p(x)$ and want to express its $n$th integral, is there a closed form for this?

Comment: It doesn't have a unique $n^{th}$ integral; this is only well-defined up to a polynomial of degree $n-1$.

Comment: I don't see your point. Take for instance $p(x) = x$, so its degree is 1. We have the 2nd integral as $\frac{x^{2}}{6}$ however.. edit: that is, plus a constant

Comment: The $n^{\rm th}$ integral of $x^r$ is 
$$
\frac{r!}{(r+n)!} x^{r+n}  \ \ (+ \ \text{arbitrary poly of degree } n-1).
$$
You can then use linearity to add the integrals of individual terms.

Comment: On the other hand, $$\underbrace{\int_0^x\int_0^{t_{n-1}}\cdots\int_0^{t_1}}_{n} t^k\;\mathrm dt\cdots\mathrm dt_{n-2}\mathrm dt_{n-1}=\frac1{(n-1)!}\int_0^x t^k (x-t)^{n-1}\mathrm dt=\frac{k!}{(n+k)!}x^{n+k}$$

Comment: Oh, now I see. I forgot to integrate the constant along with it

Comment: @Pedro You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Noticing that for $d\leqslant p$, we have that the $d$-th derivative of $x^p$ is 
$$x^{p-d}\frac{p!}{(p-d)!},$$
we get what Srivatsan wrote in his comment, that is, the $n$-th integral of $x^r$ is
$\frac{r!}{(r+n)!}x^{r+n}$ (take $p-d=r$ and $d=n$) up to a polynomial of degree $\leqslant n-1$ (as at each integration, we need to integrate the constant of the previous one). Then the result follows by linearity.

Comment: Or just take $d$ to be negative. Remember that negative iteration of a function or operator is iteration of the inverse, so differentiating a negative number of times is equivalent to integrating a positive number of times.